# python matrix transpose and zip

Tags: python

How to get the transpose of this  matrix..Any easier ,algorithmic way to do this...

1st question:

```
 Input  a=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
 Expected output a=[[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

2nd Question:

Zip gives me the following output said below,how can i zip when i dont know how many elements are there in the array,in this case i know 3 elements a[0],a[1],a[2] but how can i zip a[n] elements

```
 >>> zip(a[0],a[1],a[2])
 [(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

question answers:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> first_answer = np.transpose(a)
>>> second_answer = [list(i) for i in zip(*a)]
```

thanks to afg for helping out

Comment: What about the solution for 1st question

Comment: @Rajeev This is the answer to _both_ questions. `zip(*a)` is matrix transposition and so is its own inverse.

Comment: @Rajeev So you `map(list, zip(*a))` or `[list(row) for row in zip(*a)]` if you _really_ need the rows to be lists. Often you don't.

Comment: No idea why this was downvoted, it's actually a very clever insight into zip.  @agf's first comment is particularly insightful.

Comment: Also @luke14free for the second answer I think you mean `[list(i) for i in zip(*a)]` as zip(*a) already produces tuples.  edit: I agree with agf, not sure why you are getting numpy involved here when you don't need to.  zip(*a) with a cast to list is a much more elegant(and correct!) solution.

Answer (score 38):

Use `zip(*a)`:

```
>>> zip(*a)
[(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]
```

How it works: zip(*a) is equal to zip(a[0], a[1], a[2]).

Comment: I'd upvote this if you had `map(list, zip(*a))` since that would have answered the question without using a non-standard module.

Answer (score 4):

Solution is to use `tuple()` function.

Here is an example how to do that in your case :

```
a      = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
output = tuple(zip(*a))

print(output)
```

Comment: Please describe something about your answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use numpy.transpose

[numpy.transpose](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html)

```
>>> import numpy
>>> a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> numpy.transpose(a)
array([[1, 4, 7],
       [2, 5, 8],
       [3, 6, 9]])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `list(zip(*a))`.

By using `*a`, your list of lists can have any number of entries.

Answer (score 1):

1. Without zip

   ```
    def transpose(A):
       res = []

       for col in range(len(A[0])):
           tmp = []
           for row in range(len(A)):
               tmp.append(A[row][col])

           res.append(tmp)

       return res
   ```
2. Using zip

   ```
   def transpose(A):
       return map(list, zip(*A))
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this replacing appropriate variable

```py
import numpy as np

data = ((0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8), (9, 10, 11))

data_transpose = np.transpose(data) # replace with your code
print(data_transpose)
```