# Transpose matrix in Python without modules?

Tags: python

I'm trying to tranpose a matrix in Python 3.x without using numpy. For some reason, I'm having problems with the assignment of `new_matrix[col_num][row_num]`. For example, if I create a new instance of Matrix like test = `Matrix([[1,2,3,],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])`, the first time it goes through the inner for loop, new_matrix becomes `[[1,None,None],[1,None,None],[1,None,None]]` instead of `[[1,None,None],[None,None,None],[None,None,None]]`. I can't figure out why this is happening and why it's assigning a value to ALL the first elements of lists.

```
class Matrix:
    def __init__(self, matrix):
        self.matrix = matrix

    def transpose(self):
        new_matrix = [[None] * len(self.matrix[0])] * len(self.matrix)
        row_num = 0
        for row_num in range(len(self.matrix)):
            for col_num in range(len(self.matrix[0])):
                print(new_matrix[col_num][row_num])
                print(new_matrix)

                #assignment assigning more than one variable

                new_matrix[col_num][row_num] = self.matrix[row_num][col_num]

                print(new_matrix[col_num][row_num])
                print(new_matrix)

            col_num = 0
        return new_matrix
```

Comment: You could use `zip` to transpose. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169919/python-matrix-transpose-and-zip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new_matrix = [[None] * len(self.matrix[0])] * len(self.matrix)
```

must be replaced by

```
new_matrix = [[None for  j in self.matrix[0]] for i in self.matrix]
```

This way, all the None will be "differents".

but the shorter way  is to directly build the result with extension lists :

```
MT= [[M[j][i] for j in range(len(M))] for i in range(len(M[0]))]
```

Comment: You do not need to do this for the inner list, since `None`s are immutable.

Comment: Just realized that new_matrix should be = [[None for  j in self.matrix] for i in self.matrix[0]], not the other way around, because the number of rows in the new matrix should be the number of /columns/ in the original matrix. Other than that, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

That's because you construct the `newmatrix` with:

```
new_matrix = [[None] * len(self.matrix[0])] * len(self.matrix)
```

If you do:

```
<array-expr> * number
```

you do **not copy** that list, you **copy the reference**. So that means that when you manipulate `newmatrix[0]` you also manipulate `newmatrix[1]`, etc.

You should solve it with list-comprehension:

```
new_matrix = [[None] * len(self.matrix[0]) for _ in range(len(self.matrix))]
```

Since here you actually **construct a new list** for each row.

So the algorithm should look:

```
class Matrix:
    def __init__(self, matrix):
        self.matrix = matrix

    def transpose(self):
        new_matrix = [[None] * len(self.matrix[0]) for _ in range(len(self.matrix))]
        row_num = 0
        for row_num in range(len(self.matrix)):
            for col_num in range(len(self.matrix[0])):
                print(new_matrix[col_num][row_num])
                print(new_matrix)

                #assignment assigning more than one variable

                new_matrix[col_num][row_num] = self.matrix[row_num][col_num]

                print(new_matrix[col_num][row_num])
                print(new_matrix)

            col_num = 0
        return new_matrix
```

Comment: code with highlighting (...well boldface)! i'm impressed!

Comment: @hiroprotagonist: well it took some time to figure out how to do it, but like Python, everything is so easy on SO. It's like `import antigravity` :p

Comment: i'll keep that trick of yours in mind; may come in handy. thanks for that! apropos `import antigravity`: i love `xkcd-style` for matplotlib for drawing hand-wavy plots...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint:

```
In [9]: arr = [[None] * 2] * 3

In [10]: arr
Out[10]: [[None, None], [None, None], [None, None]]

In [11]: arr[1][1] = 2

In [12]: arr
Out[12]: [[None, 2], [None, 2], [None, 2]]
```

---

Do you see the problem?

The list replication (`*` operator) repeats the *same nested list object* within the containing list. Instead, you should be creating a new list every time.