# How to change a list of lists without copying?

Tags: python, list

I have a matrix which is given in a list of lists:

```
board = [[1, 0, 0, 1], [-1, -1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

What I want to do is change the board but without copying.
I want to change it into a columns board:

```
def foo(board):

    change board to columns board

board = foo(board)
```

This is the result:

```
board = [[1, -1, 0], [0, -1, 0], [0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0]]
```

Problem is it creates a new variable with the same name (board) and doesn't change the original board.

I need to change the original board as I need to use it in different places afterward.

Cannot return the board, as I would've gladly done without thinking about it (not allowed).

Even tried:

```
a = foo(board)
board.clear()
board += a
```

Which should work but for some reason bugs my program. any help would be appreciated

Comment: You can do `board[:] = foo(board)` <- this will change values inside the `board` variable

Comment: what do you mean by "for some reason bugs my program"? what error are you getting?

Comment: While it is possible to modify the list from inside the `foo()` function, this is likely not the best solution to your original problem. Such side effects lead to difficult-to-find bugs because values are changed unexpectedly. Can you provide more context about what you are trying to do here?

Comment: @AndrejKesely board[:] works great, thanks!  actually tried a different way which worked too, but this one's better

Comment: @Personman seems i had another similar problem which is why it bugged my program, no error received, just wrong outcome

Comment: @Code-Apprentice yea i know it seems a bit unnatural, some school work requirements so had to do it that way. need the board itself to update in the function and then use it in another one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* do it in-place, but since it changes the entire structure of the board (number of sublists etc.) it does IMHO not make much sense and seems a bit unnatural. If the only problem is that you have other references pointing to the same board, you could assign to the slice `board[:]` to overwrite all the contents of `board` with the new board, *without* assigning a new value to `board` itself.

```
def swap(b):
    return list(map(list, zip(*b)))

>>> board = [[1, 0, 0, 1], [-1, -1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
>>> also_board = board
>>> board[:] = swap(board)
>>> also_board
[[1, -1, 0], [0, -1, 0], [0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0]]
```

This is not in-place in a memory-point-of-view, but for your purpose it should work.

Answer (score 0):

That is called a transposition. You can achieve this by spreading the 2D list into zip and converting each item to a list:

```
board = [[1, 0, 0, 1], [-1, -1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
bid = id(board)
print(board)
# The posed question insists on mutating board so here it is.
for i, item in enumerate(list(item) for item in zip(*board)):
    try:
        board[i] = item
    except IndexError:
        board.append(item)

print(bid == id(board))
print(board)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 0, 0, 1], [-1, -1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
True
[[1, -1, 0], [0, -1, 0], [0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0]]
```

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19888067/1913726).

Comment: Edited. Same board. Updated. More code. Now the board has been mutated rather than replaced. The code with mutation takes over twice as long as replacing the board with `board = [list(item) for item in zip(*board)]` which is the comprehensive equivalent to `list(map(list, zip(*b)))` in the accepted answer. Checked with timeit in Jupyter notebook: 12.2 µs ± 47 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each) vs 5.89 µs ± 23.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

Comment: `board[:]` creates a new board in the accepted answer. It has a different id.

Comment: The above comments are comments in response to a deleted comment that the answer that was there `board = [list(item) for item in zip(*board)]` doesn't update the existing items in board.

Answer (score 0):

**Just for fun**

```
def transpose(matrix):
    rows = len(matrix)
    if rows < 1:
        raise ValueError("matrix has to have at least one row")
    rowlen = len(matrix[0])
    if rowlen == 0:
        raise ValueError("rows must not be empty")
    if rowlen == 1 and rows == 1:
        return
    for i in range(1, rows):
        if len(matrix[i]) != rowlen:
            raise ValueError("rows must have the same lenght")
    index = 0
    while index < rowlen:
        newrow = []
        for c in range(rows):
            newrow.append(matrix[c].pop(0))
        matrix.append(newrow)
        index += 1
        if index == rowlen:
            while(len(matrix[0]) == 0):
                matrix.pop(0)


board = [[1,0,0,1], [-1,-1,1,1], [0,0,0,0]]
print("id|{}: {}".format(id(board), board))
print("transposing...")
transpose(board)
print("id|{}: {}".format(id(board), board))
```

**Output**

id|140328172362568: [[1, 0, 0, 1], [-1, -1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0]]

transposing...

id|140328172362568: [[1, -1, 0], [0, -1, 0], [0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0]]

**It's very slow, better stick with zip**